# Not able to login, getting /etc/profile error while trying to login

Tags: login-screen, system

I'm not able to login to my desktop. Every time I try to login to my system I get this error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You've not provided any OS/product/release details; are we to guess?

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> and then log in with your username and password.

From there, run:

```
nano /etc/profile
```

and edit the file.

The error says that there is a problem on lines 29 and 30 of the file.

According to the error, the screenshot is blurry but it looks like you're missing a `'` to close an unmatched `'` earlier in the file. You need to insert the missing `'` where it belongs, probably somewhere on line 29 or 30. This assumes you're not also missing anything after the quotation mark.

Unexpected EOF error can be something simple like an unmatched or unclosed quotation mark (like in this case) or even a missing space or sometimes, although more rarely, even an extra added empty space at the end of the file.

Comment: You can see in [this similar question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/824406/167115) that the user accidentally pasted something into their `.bashrc` file to cause the same error.